# Inserting in MySQL Table Error

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder is anyone can help me with this annoying problem. Trying to insert some data into a table. In the mean time, I want to leave out some fields and not insert something there. For some reason I'm getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING` error. Is there something I'm doing wrong below?

Your help will be appreciated.

```
     <?php

        function sqlEscape($string){     
        return "'".mysql_real_escape_string($string)."'";
        } 

              if(      $_GET['location']  == '' 
               ||  $_GET['name']      == ''   
                   ||  $_GET['school']    == ''  
               ||  $_GET['reason']    == ''              
                   ||  $_GET['address']   == ''
               ||  $_GET['postcode']  == ''
               ||  $_GET['email']     == ''
               ||  $_GET['telephone'] == '') {     

        exit('You missed a value');
  }  
 include('theConfig.php');
 $con = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error()) ;  


    if (!$con){   
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }  mysql_select_db($db, $con);  //$description = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[description]); 


 $sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO applications (location, name, school, reason, address, postcode, email, telephone, town, county, state, country)
         VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,'','')', 

                 sqlEscape($_GET['location']),                                  
                sqlEscape($_GET['name']),                 
               sqlEscape($_GET['school']),                          
                sqlEscape($_GET['reason']),                 

                sqlEscape($_GET['address']),                
                sqlEscape($_GET['postcode']),                 
                sqlEscape($_GET['email']),                
                sqlEscape($_GET['telephone'])); 

        if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)){     
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
        }  
      header('Location: thankyou.php');     
      mysql_close($con)  

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO applications (location, name, school, reason, address, postcode, email, telephone, town, county, state, country)
         VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,'','')',
```

You have '', '')' which is incorrect, b/c the first quote in this sequence closes the string, so it's actually three strings togather: 'INSERT ... ', then ', ', and then ')'. You must escape quotes in the string with backslash or use double quotes to enclose whole string:

(escaping)

```
 $sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO applications (location, name, school, reason, address, postcode, email, telephone, town, county, state, country)
         VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,\'\',\'\')',
```

(using double quotes)

```
 $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO applications (location, name, school, reason, address, postcode, email, telephone, town, county, state, country)
         VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,'','')",
```

Comment: And after you fix this compile time error, you'll get another run time "Too few arguments" error. The following answer describes how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Got it working now. Thanks to everyone who gave me their suggestions and help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You should have values set for town and county - or set with default value (empty string like the others):

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO applications (location, name, school, reason, address, postcode, email, telephone, town, county, state, country)
         VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, '','','','')", ... )
```

Edit:
Also - use double quotes to surround the first `sprintf` parameter as single quotes are used within...

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see above I have empty values for town and county. Not sure if there's something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

You use single quotes for the string in your `sprintf()` call, but you also use single quotes inside the string as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
function sqlEscape($string){     
    return "'".mysql_real_escape_string($string)."'";
    }
```

to

```
function sqlEscape($string){     
    return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
}
```

or better yet just throw it in your sprintf

```
$sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO applications (location, name, school, reason, address, postcode, email, telephone, town, county, state, country)
     VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','','')', 

             mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['location']),
```

etc...

note I changed %s to '%s'